# nodejs v8 garbage collection when calling native addon

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection, electron, node.js-addon

I'm developing an electron app with native addon on mac, and the workflow of all the components is like this:
js in electron -> call addon.node(c++ native addon)  ->call dylib using dlopen and dlsym.

the addon get string from js by this way:

```
NAN_METHOD(CallAsyncFunction) {

    // actions guarantee dll is loaded
    //....

    const char* funcName = *Utf8String(info[0]->ToString());
    const char* funcParam = *Utf8String(info[1]->ToString());

    //get function pointer by dlsym
    //call the function in dylib

}
```

Yesterday we found a bug which is very interesting. It happened when the string param is very long, for a funcParam string with the size about 400 bytes or even longer, the log in dylib shows that the length of funcParam arrived is 0 while the funcName sent in the same way is having correct length and content. After some debug I guessed that the string might have been garbage-collected ,so I created a string object to save the funcParam and then send the new pointer to dylib again, it worked!

My question is: How does the js engine work so that the string resource pointer is visitable in js native addon while unavailable in the dylib the native addon calls?

Answer (score 0):

I think the actual problem is that you're creating and destroying the `Utf8Value` in the same line and are trying to dereference a dangling pointer. It should instead be

```
Utf8String str(info[0]->ToString());
const char* funcName = *str;
```